# validation does not work with a parameter and a cast in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a slight issue when trying to execute a proc below:

```
exec SupportAudit.BI.CreateMCCInvoiceReversal 'APCCP/000', 29923
```

I have a piece of code in a proc that checks if an invoice number already exists:

```
        -- see if invoice number already exisits
if exists (select 1 from Jet2Fees.Discount.Invoice where InvoiceNumber = @InvoiceNumber + '/' +  cast(@InvoiceID as varchar(50)))
            BEGIN;
                set @errormsg = 'Invoice Number already exists';
                THROW 99999, @errormsg, 1
            END;
```

Currently it still inserts a row even though the invoice number exists. If I replace the      `where InvoiceNumber = @InvoiceNumber  +  cast(InvoiceID as varchar)` with `where InvoiceNumber = 'APCCP/00029923'`. The validation works as it should. So my question is why does it now work when I use where `InvoiceNumber = @InvoiceNumber  +  cast(InvoiceID as varchar)`? What should this line be?

Below is the code of the proc:

```
    ALTER Procedure [BI].[CreateMCCInvoiceReversal]
    (

        @InvoiceNumber      varchar(255),
        @InvoiceId          int,
    )
    AS

    /**
    ** Script to create MCC Invoice Reversal
    **
    ** Table(s) updated: Discount.Invoice
    **
    ** Version 1.0 - MKP - 25/08/2016 - Written
    **
    **/

    BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    declare @errormsg           varchar(250);
    declare @OutputList         [Core].[RollbackOutputList];
    declare @CountRows          int;

    Set @procname = OBJECT_NAME(@@ProcID)

    BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRAN MCCInvoiceReversal

            INSERT INTO [Jet2Fees].Discount.Invoice
                    (
                    InvoiceNumber,
                    )

            OUTPUT '[Jet2Fees].Discount.Invoice', 'InvoiceID', inserted.InvoiceId,
                                    Core.insXMLFragment('InvoiceId')+Core.addnlXMLFragment('InvoiceId', inserted.InvoiceId)


                INTO @OutputList

                SELECT @InvoiceNumber  +  cast(InvoiceID as varchar),
                FROM Jet2Fees.Discount.Invoice
                WHERE InvoiceId = @InvoiceId

                if( @@ROWCOUNT <> 1)
                    BEGIN
                    ROLLBACK TRAN MCCInvoiceReversal
                    set @errormsg = 'Record not found, please check details entered';
                    THROW 99999, @errormsg, 1
                    END

        --see if invoice number already exists
if exists (select 1 from Jet2Fees.Discount.Invoice where InvoiceNumber = @InvoiceNumber + '/' +  cast(@InvoiceID as varchar(50)))
            BEGIN;
                set @errormsg = 'Invoice Number already exists';
                THROW 99999, @errormsg, 1
            END;

    exec Core.insertRollbackXML @outputList, @TaskLogid, @procname

    COMMIT TRANSACTION MCCInvoiceReversal

    END TRY
```

Comment: *always* give an explicit length to `VARCHAR`. And the answer to your question most likely is: The line should be `cast(InvoiceID as varchar(8))` or an appropriate length

Comment: `where InvoiceNumber = @InvoiceNumber  + '/' +  cast(InvoiceID as varchar(10))`?

Comment: You're surprised that it doesn't automagically know how many `0`s to prepend to pad an integer when converting to a string to match your data formats?

Comment: Rather than rolling back - would't you be better to see if it EXISTS before you actually do anything?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well, the leading zeros are part of `@InvoiceNumber` and are passed to the sp, so no issue there

Comment: Still having issues when included a character length after the varchar

Comment: dude, I didn't even realize that you are using `InvoiceID` instead of `@InvoiceID`, you need to use the correct parameter: `where InvoiceNumber = @InvoiceNumber + '/' + cast(@InvoiceID as varchar(8))`

Comment: @Lamak Yeah this is the other problem I get. i tried it before using `@InvoiceId` and what happens is that it always throws the error, even if the number hasn't existed before. Update: I forgot to add the / but even when i have done this it now just continues to insert

Comment: I'll update the proc to how it looks like now after your suggestions, though still same issue

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that parameter have following values

```
@InvoiceNumber ='APCCP/000'
@InvoiceId = 29923
```

Now see what you are doing wrong in where clause

```
where InvoiceNumber = @InvoiceNumber + '/' +  cast(@InvoiceID as varchar(50))
```

That is `@InvoiceNumber + '/' +  cast(@InvoiceID as varchar(50))` OUTPUT of this string will be similar to `'APCCP/000/29923'` and your where condition becomes like this

```
where InvoiceNumber = 'APCCP/000/29923'
```

And According to me that's only reason to fail your query. try this where condition without using `/`

```
WHERE InvoiceNumber = @InvoiceNumber  +  cast(@InvoiceID as varchar(50))
```

Comment: yeah tried this before the / and issue is that validation will always be called, even if number doesn't exist before

Comment: the problem may be with `;` in `BEGIN;` try to remove this `;` from `BEGIN`

Answer (score 0):

use the below script..

```
select @CountRows = count(*)
      from Jet2Fees.Discount.Invoice
      where InvoiceNumber = Ltrim(rtrim(@InvoiceNumber)) + LTRIM (rtrim (cast(@InvoiceID as varchar(50))))-- should match with the max length of your invoice id


      if        @CountRows >= 1
            begin
                ROLLBACK TRAN MCCInvoiceReversal
                set @errormsg = 'Invoice Number already exists';
                THROW 99999, @errormsg, 1
            end
```

Comment: Still having the same issue UnniKrishnan

Comment: did your invoice number contains the character '/' ??

Comment: Yes it did, in the table it is displayed as 'APCCPI/00029923' as an example

Comment: I'll update the proc to how it looks like now after your suggestions, though still same issue

Comment: It should be as an example `@Invoicenumber` 'APCCP/000' and `@InvoiceId` 29923

Comment: Still same problem. invoiceID could be any length you see

Comment: Does the SELECT statement in the proc need to change as well within the insert?